# Edit alternate openid

Tags: feature-request, openid, user-accounts

It was be nice but not essential to have page to change alt openid.

At the moment to change your alternate openid you have to:

1. Click **swap** link.
2. Click **change openid** link.
3. Provide required information.
4. Click **swap** link.